# Error: Objects of type lm not supported by autoplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a simple function that accepts two arguments:

A linear model and a string that corresponds to a color, in that order.

It should create a Residuals vs Fitted and Q-Q plot for this linear model, and color the points according to the string argument like this:

> demo_lm <- lm(ExpenditurePerStud ~ State, data = clean_colleges)
>
> answer7(demo_lm, "#34925E")

This is what I have tried:

```
library(ggplot2)

demo_lm <- lm(ExpenditurePerStud ~ State, data = clean_colleges)

answer7 <- function( my_lm , color_str) 
{
  autoplot(my_lm, which = 1:2, smooth.colour = color_str,
           data = clean_colleges, colour = color_str) +
    theme_bw()
}
```

But it throws the Error: Objects of type lm not supported by autoplot when I call `answer7(demo_lm, "#34925E")`

Comment: Why do you use `autoplot`?

Comment: Does this function _have_ to be written for `ggplot2`?

Comment: @bouncyball Yes .Roland I am not sure but I think for the Residuals vs Fitted and QQ Plot

Comment: As far as I can see ggplot2 only provides the generic and no methods for `autoplot`. If you want to use it here, you need to find a package that defines an `lm` method or write one yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something to get you started. The error message from `autoplot` clearly indicates that it cannot handle `lm` objects. Just extract the residuals and fitted values, then plot:

```
answer7 <- function(my_lm, color_str){
    resids <- residuals(my_lm)
    fitted <- fitted(my_lm)

   p_vs_r <- ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x = fitted, y = resids))+
        geom_point(colour = color_str)

   qq_r <- ggplot(data = NULL, aes(sample = resids))+
        stat_qq(colour = color_str)

   plot(p_vs_r)
   plot(qq_r)

}
```

It may be useful to take a look at the `multiplot` function in the **`Rmisc`** package if you want both plots on the same device.

Comment: although not recommended, one can force the export of `autoplot.lm`. For example `ggfortify:::autoplot.lm(lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars), which = 1:2)`

Answer (score 2):

The error shouldn't occur when using `ggfortify`, which enables `autoplot` to use more different object types.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

demo_lm <- lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars)

answer7 <- function(my_lm) 
{
  autoplot(my_lm, which = 1:2) +
    theme_bw()
}
answer7(demo_lm)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install ggfortify before calling autoplot. I also had the same error and solved it that way.