# type numeric not supported by autoplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've seen other errors of objects not supported by autoplot but not of type numeric.
[example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056144/r-ggfortify-objects-of-type-prcomp-not-supported-by-autoplot)
[example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165401/error-objects-of-type-lm-not-supported-by-autoplot)

Say I create some random numbers

```
require(ggfortify)
require(ggplot2)
```

`data <- c(.034,0343,0343,.0653,.034,0343,0343,.0653)`

```
autoplot(data)

Error: Objects of type numeric not supported by autoplot.
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Exactly what kind of plot where you expecting here? Not sure what the desired output is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data must be in time series format and not numeric

```
autoplot(ts(data))
```

Comment: `autoplot()` is a generic function that supports over 50 different classes. A time series is just one. See `methods(autoplot)` to see all the other types of things you can pass.

Comment: the comment in the answer could be phrased differently. What matters is the code solves the problem I was asking